# Facebook - incentivize people

Tags: facebook, policy

There are many apps out there which incentivize people for sharing or liking a page. Although facebook mention in there platform policy:

> You must not incentivize people to use social plugins or to like a page. This includes offering rewards, or gating apps or app content based on whether or not a person has liked a Page.

So Facebook does not care about that? Or have those apps a kind of contract that allows them to do so?

Comment: it is not allowed. if you see it, report it.

Comment: We do care. You can message me if you see apps doing it.

Comment: @WizKid how can I message you?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Facebook policy (https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) which states

"Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, or check-in at a place. Don’t incentivize other actions",

inventivizing people for sharing or liking pages is not allowed.

However, incentivizing people to check-in at places, seems to be no problem even though these posts are similar to normal shares!?. One of the most popular apps where this is possible is Swarms / Foursquare (https://www.swarmapp.com).